# Blocking Adult Websites in Android

Tags: java, android, logging, traffic

I'd like to monitor the Android Log for a list of adult IP addresses (I already have a list of common adult sites) Has anyone seen an example of how one can monitor the log for specific IP traffic? I've searched both Google and StackOverflow for information regarding how this can be done - but have not found much information.

Comment: There are existing Cyber Nanny style apps to stop children from going to inappropriate sites.  However you won't be able to block all traffic without root access, with root access it's quite easy.  Read about [the creation of AdFree](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=509997).

Answer (score 2):

That isn't the right way to do it-  a lot of servers are shared.  A single IP address can host a dozen websites, and only one of those may be adult.

I'd also be very surprised if this kind of app is possible without rooting-  it would be a severe privacy problem to allow one app to sniff IPs from another.  There's definitely no global log of network connections made that I know of, and Google is very careful about preventing apps from interacting with each other in this manner.

Comment: There are many parental control application on the Android Market - why would I not be able to design/build one as they have?

Comment: I see over 1000 results returned in the Android Market for such applications. 

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=parental+controls&c=apps

Comment: THey don't block IP addresses.  What apparently you can do is set your own app to be the registered handler for an address, via intent filters.  But there is no way to know what IP another app is going to.

Comment: I fail to believe you cannot monitor the log / logcat for internet traffic. Are you saying it is impossible to do so?

Comment: Yes, purposely.  It would be a huge privacy risk to do so.  Imagine if every ad infested POS on your phone that's barely a step better than malware could sniff all of your internet surfing.  Not a good idea, which is why they don't allow it.  What you can do is like I said above, but it won't work well.  You could also set up a proxy server and configure your phone to use it, which is what most if not all parental control apps do.

Comment: The other thing you can do of course is root the phone and use one of the many tools to redirect websites under linux, such as editing /etc/hosts.